# Node.js mocha process (_mocha) doesn't exit upon CTRL-C

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

When a `mocha` test takes a while to complete, hitting CTRL-C exits the `mocha` command but doesn't exit the test runner, "_mocha", and the test continues. Anybody know if this by design?

```
/* 
 * test/mocha-kill-test.js
 */
describe("Mocha Timeout Test", function() {

  this.timeout(10e3);

  it("should exit when hitting CTRL-C", function(done) {
    var count = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      if (count++ < 10) {
        console.log("  WAIT " + count);
      } else {
        console.log("  DONE");
        clearInterval(timer);
        done();
      }
    }, 1e3);
  });

});
```

This test will run for 10 seconds and then exit. If you try to interrupt it from the terminal with a CTRL-C (or otherwise send it a SIGINT), the test runner will continue to run and you'll see something like this in your shell.

```
shell> mocha test/mocha-kill-test.js 

    WAIT 1
  WAIT 2
^Cshell>   WAIT 3
  WAIT 4
  WAIT 5
  WAIT 6
  WAIT 7
  WAIT 8
  WAIT 9
  WAIT 10
  DONE
․

  1 passing (11s)
```

I see that `mocha` is supposed to catch SIGINT and do a `runner.abort()` but this can't be the intended behavior, right?

> **node** v0.10.26
>   **mocha** 1.18.2

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Mocha's supporter feedback about the issue:
"you need to ensure the code Mocha is running actually stops at some point."

See link below for more details:

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1362

According to other developers the code below will keep the Mocha process alive even after trying to kill it with CTRL+C:

```
echo "while(1);" > file.js
mocha -w file.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly when they fixed it but in Mocha 2.1.0 and 2.2.1, if I hit Ctrl-C during the execution of your example file, I get the behavior that you were looking for: everything stops, right away.